# slideToggle causing little glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

I've created a toggle button which shows (toggles) hidden elements when clicked. Overall it works fine but when You click the button `CLICK HERE` you'll notice that the uncovered content makes a little jump/glitch at the end. What's the cause of this? Here's the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/0ybkknaf/

Answer (score 1):

it is due to your .form-data margin.

It has a top and bottom margin of 20px, but that 40px margin space does not exist when that element is hidden, the jump is this extra space being added

Answer (score 0):

It was your submit button bottom margin.... You need to nullify it.

```
.submit, .show_inputs {
    margin: 15px auto;
   .......
}
```

Add this line below

```
.show_inputs {
   margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Here is the working jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0ybkknaf/1/